# Cbool result is translate in concatenation

Tags: iis, asp-classic, plesk

I have a strange result with this ASP code :

```
<%
Dim TEST_variable
TEST_variable = "0"
TEST_variable = CBool("0")
Response.Write "1- TEST_variable :"
Response.Write TEST_variable
Response.Write "<br/>"
Response.Write "2- TEST_variable :" & TEST_variable 
%>
```

This Code display this result :

1- TEST_variable :False

2- TEST_variable :Faux

Why this `Response.Write "2- TEST_variable :" & TEST_variable` translate *false* to *faux* ?

Answer (score 2):

beacause of the string concatenation vbscript "casts" the variant of subtype bool (TEST_variable) to a variant of the subtype string. during this cast a bool is translated to the language of the webserver.

Comment: Is there a way around this behavior? 
Because I have a problem in my SQL queries

Comment: well there is always a way can you post some code? when you create a string for a SQL query then your variable does not Need to bee a bool, right? so you could just use a string...